# C++ operator overload with pointer object

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am working on comparing my object with another object of the same type.

```
Entry<string, string>* name =  new Entry<string, string>(names[9], paths[9]);
Entry<string, string>* name2 = new Entry<string, string>(names[9], paths[9]);

bool isSame = name == name2;
```

This is always false.

In my implementation, I have tried a few things but with no luck.

```
template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
bool Entry<KeyType, ItemType>::operator==(Entry<KeyType, ItemType>* rightHandItem)
{
    KeyType key = rightHandItem->getKey();
    return (searchKey == key);
}

template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
bool Entry<KeyType, ItemType>::operator>(Entry<KeyType, ItemType>* rightHandItem)
{
    KeyType key = rightHandItem->getKey();
    return (searchKey > key);
}
template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
bool Entry<KeyType, ItemType>::operator<(Entry<KeyType, ItemType>* rightHandItem)
{
    KeyType key = rightHandItem->getKey();
    return (searchKey < key);
}
```

This is my class header file

```
#pragma once
template<class KeyType, class ItemType>
class Entry
{
public:
    Entry();
    Entry(KeyType& searchKey);
    Entry(KeyType& searchKey, ItemType newEntry);
    ~Entry();
    ItemType getItem() const;
    KeyType getKey() const;
    void setItem(const ItemType& newEntry);
    bool operator==(const Entry<KeyType, ItemType>& rightHandItem) const;
    bool operator>(const Entry<KeyType, ItemType>& rightHandItem) const;
    bool operator<(const Entry<KeyType, ItemType>& rightHandItem) const;

    bool operator==(Entry<KeyType, ItemType>* rightHandItem);
    bool operator>(Entry<KeyType, ItemType>* rightHandItem);
    bool operator<(Entry<KeyType, ItemType>* rightHandItem);
private:
    ItemType Item;
    KeyType searchKey;
protected:
    void setKey(const KeyType& searchKey);
};

#include "Entry.cpp"
```

The only way I can get this to work is if I declare entry as an object and not a pointer.

I thought this question would be a quick search but I have been unable to find a duplicate. Let me know if this has been asked before.

How do I compare the two pointers?

Comment: you cannot overload operators for pointers (as the rhs). Cant you simply compare instances instead of pointers?

Comment: "This is always false." - because it is comparing pointers. Why do you need to allocate these things with `new`?

Comment: *Why* are you using pointers in the first place? What is the reason for that? You don't have any virtual functions, or inheritance, so there's no polymorphism involved that you need pointers for. And with proper [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) adherence you don't really need pointers that much.

Comment: As for solving it with pointers anyway (even though I highly recommend *against* it), think about the dereference operator.

Comment: I will try working the pointers out. If they are not needed, I will remove them.

Comment: I do not want to fight c++ lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Entry<string, string>* name =  new Entry<string, string>(names[9], paths[9]);
> Entry<string, string>* name2 = new Entry<string, string>(names[9], paths[9]);
>
> bool isSame = name == name2;
> ```
>
> This is always false.

It is always `false`, because you are comparing the adresses of two distinct objects. Actually in general there is not much you can do with a pointer unless you derference it. If you want to call `Entry::operator==` you would need to dereference the pointers, as in:

```
bool isSame = *name == *name2;
```

Btw, the question arises, why do you use pointers in the first place? Just use plain objects and your problem is gone:

```
 auto name =  Entry<string, string>(names[9], paths[9]);
 auto name2 = Entry<string, string>(names[9], paths[9]);

 bool isSame = name == name2;
```

this will work as expected, given you provide a `Entry::operator==(Entry)`

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess I thought I needed pointers because I am using this Entry class in my Binary Search Tree. I thought the item in my node had to be a pointer.

Comment: @Christian4423 I know teachers will tell you otherwise, but the cases where you really need pointers are actually surprisingly rare